# emacs で、縦分割されているウィンドウを横分割にしたい

Tags: emacs

emacs で、縦に分割したウィンドウを、表示されているバッファはそのままで、横分割にしたいです。ひとまず、2分割でこれが実現したいと思っています。

どうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/daichirata/emacs-rotate が、私の欲しかったもののようすです。

`M-x rotate-layout` で、 window のレイアウトを切り替えることができます。

Answer (score 1):

関数名は適当です。

```lisp
(defun window-split-vertical-to-horizontal ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((nw (window-buffer (next-window))))
    (delete-other-windows)
    (split-window-horizontally)
    (set-window-buffer (next-window) nw)))
```